# Maven: How to activate inactive proxies via command line?

Tags: command-line, maven-2, proxy

I have a proxy server configured for Maven via the per-user settings.xml file.  The documentation snipped of the default settings.xml template suggests that it is possible to influence which of the configured proxies is used via a command-line switch:

```xml
<!-- proxies
 | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
 | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
 | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
 |-->
```

However, I have found no documentation whatsoever on how this is supposed to work. [The Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) has very much the same template, but no mention whatsoever of a command-line switch or else.

So, suppose I have a proxy configured, but marked as `<active>false</active>`, like in this example:

```xml
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>firstProxy</id>
        <active>false</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>proxy.example.invalid</host>
        <port>3128</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

As per the comment there would be some way to for instance "activate" it, possibly giving its id or something like that. Trying the "obvious" using `mvn -Dproxies.proxy.firstProxy.active=true java:compile`, without success.

I'm very new to Maven and cannot shake the feeling that I am barking up the wrong tree in some way. Is what I am trying to do even possible at all—if so, can anyone point me to a description on how to do it—or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Why do you need to activate/deactivate the proxy via command line?

Comment: I am working in several different networks. Some of them require no proxy, others do, so I end up having to constantly switch proxies. Seeing that 'active' flag I thought that would be a reasonably nice way of switching between them, as Maven unfortunately doesn't seem to care about $HTTP_PROXY…

Comment: Why not checking in the .m2 areas (without repository) and create a branch in git which represents the other area. This will make changing very easy.

Comment: I'm already doing something similar, but it feels like an even uglier workaround. That's why I wondered if there were any way to make use of that `<active>` flag above.

Comment: What is ugly about changing the configuration controled by a version control tool on different machines.

Comment: So I guess the base question that still remains: I can pass properties to Maven via the `-D` flag. Is it possibly to modify settings set in settings.xml this way? If not, the comments in that file seem rather bogus…

Comment: May be this helps: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4802

Comment: Ah btw. why not defining a different settings.xml file on command line via mvn -s settings.xml file ? (completely missed that).

Comment: And found an other interesting thing: http://www.morgan-design.com/2011/07/bypassing-proxies-by-setting-maven-pom.html

Answer (score 1):

As @khmarbaise suggested:

use many settings.xml, e.g put them in project root then

```
mvn package -s setings.A.xml

mvn package -s setings.B.xml
```